# How can I get all the posts that are related with a specific taxonomy term?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query, taxonomy, tax-query

I'm using the technique below for that (getting all the post related with a taxonomy term), but for some reason if I have some posts with the term **e** and post with the term **English** I get  them all and not only those which are related to **English**.

```
 'tax_query' => array(
      array(
            'taxonomy' => 'origin',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'English',

     )
 )
```

Is there a way to get all the post related with the English term only?
I'm not sure but right now seems to be working as a like operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
  'origin' => 'English'
)
```

Also, it should be pretty easy. Do some research.

Comment: That doesn't work, I took a look into the wordpress reference but I don't see a reference for that.

Comment: this should work, use "english", instead of "English".

Comment: Thanks,  but I'm still getting the same results as the other way I was doing it.

Comment: can you post whole taxonomy `query` you used?